# Unable to execute PHP files on nginx server.

Tags: php, nginx

Unable to execute PHP files on nginx server.

Below is my default.conf file.

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.php index.htm; 
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "unable to execute" mean? What URL are you trying to access? What is the HTTP response? What appears in nginx's error log?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you read the Pitfalls page on [Multiple Index Directives](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#Multiple_Index_Directives).

You should not put those index directives under a location as suggested here, it's not the correct way to do it (it works but it's wrong).

Comment: Thanks for comment. Your link says it's wrong to input `index` anywhere, but I don't know, if `index` included to `http` section already. It's good advice if you're building your site configuration, but in this case it's better to include it to make sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You also could to use a try_files directive:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

And that root line under location ~ \.php$ looks fishy ...

http {
   upstream phpfpm {
      #server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      server 127.0.0.1:9000;
   }
}

server {
         ...
      index index.php;

      location / {
         ...
         error_page 404 = @phpfpm;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
         include        fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

         #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         #fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_pass   phpfpm;
      }
```

Think that would work, it's not a recipe, you need to work your config into it.